# Preserving/Copying formula so that whenever a new response is added it automatically applies Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Sheet where I have columns where I have applied certain formula to calculate the cell value in Column. It is connected to google spreadsheet response.Whenever new response is added Data is entered in the row. I have tried to work on the script so that whenever new record is entered is should copy the formula from the above row automatically so that I dont need to drag down.

I have columns as

A       |       B      |     C         |     D

23      |       22     |     45        |     1

In the Column C I am trying to add the A and B and in the D I substract the values.

I have used the following code to copy the formula. But it isn't working. It is basically copying the same values as the above row has. Can someone help me in figuring out the error and fix the code to get the correct output.

Thanks

```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   function onOpen() {
   var menu = [{name:"Insert New Record", 
   functionName:"insertRecord"}];
   ss.addMenu("Options", menu);
   }
   function insertRecord() {

   var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();                  
   var lRow = sh.getLastRow();                    
   var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();                 

   var range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);        
   var formulas = range.getFormulas();           

  sh.insertRowsBefore(lRow, 1);                 

  var newRange = sh.getRange(lRow, 1, 1, lCol);  
  range.copyTo(newRange);                        

  newRange.setFormulas(formulas);                
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line
`range.copyTo(newRange);` with // like so:

`//range.copyTo(newRange);`

That line is copying the data from range a to range b.

You are then copying the formulas from range a to range b.

You don't need to copy the data if you are replacing it with a formula right afterwards.

If this has no effect, try using .getFormula and .setFormula instead of .getFormulas and .setFormulas. .getFormulas will treat the data as completely different data set to .getFormula, read the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula

In short, .getFormula is a string, where as .getFormulas save as a 2d array containing strings.

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("C2").setFormula("=(A2+B2)");
  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getActiveRange(2,3,lr-1);
  ss.getRange("C2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

 }

Comment: I used the above function as well . But it isn't working and also here I need to set the formula. I was hoping is there a function I can use to copy the formula I have set in for the cell

Comment: Yes, use .getFormula() and .setFormula(). NOT .getFormulas() or .setFormulas(). If you still can't figure out the cause of your issue, share a copy of the sheet with edit rights to my gmail account so I can better assist you. sparkycbass@gmail.com